# What does Bob Coecke mean in saying that "you can prove that the abstract algebra is equivalent to merely drawing some pictures"?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0510032, Bob Coecke says that "at an [sic] highly abstract level you can prove that the abstract algebra is equivalent to merely drawing
some pictures". Can anyone expand on this statement? I couldn't figure out which references tackle this directly.

Comment: I'm not sure what he means, but as a for instance, you can realize a monoid as a category (with associated diagrams) on one element. A group is a cateogory with one element where every arrow is an isomorphism.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string+diagram

Comment: Worth explicit mention: the quoted  remark is immediately followed by "(see the last section of these notes for some references on this)". Did you browse the cited literature?

Comment: The comments seem to have enough information to answer your question. However, the use of *merely* makes the sentence worth ignoring, to be honest...

Comment: On some level isn't all of math equivalent to merely drawing some pictures?